# display two values separated by / in <facet> tag

Tags: visualforce

I want to display grandTotal1/grandTotal2 information as 10/20 in Footer as Grand Total. But I can't work it out.

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        Total Students/Total Classes
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!myBean.value1}" />&nbsp;/&nbsp; 
    <apex:outputText value="{!myBean.value2}" /> 
    <apex:facet name="footer">
        <apex:outputText value="{!grandTotal1}" />&nbsp;/&nbsp;
        <apex:outputText value="{!grandTotal2}" /> 
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: It's showing both values but not "/" mark is it?

Comment: it only shows one value (second one). no / or first value appears.

Comment: for now, I will use string variable to put things as "10/20" (example). if someone has better solutions, I will be happy to learn.

Comment: Have you tried using the HTML code for this character `/`? Try this: &nbsp;&#47;&nbsp;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them both in the same outputText:

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        Total Students/Total Classes
    </apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText value="{!myBean.value1} / {!myBean.value2}" /> 
    <apex:facet name="footer">
        <apex:outputText value="{!grandTotal1} / {!grandTotal2}" /> 
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: I will accept this solution as this one requires much lesser lines of codes. Thanks you all for sharing the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

====Edited for one column solution===
All you need is a < apex:outputPanel>. Try the following code which works for me:

```
                 <apex:column >
                      <apex:facet name="header">
                         Total Students/Total Classes
                      </apex:facet>
                      <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}" />&nbsp;/&nbsp; 
                      <apex:outputText value="{!account.rating}" /> 
                      <apex:facet name="footer">
                        <apex:outputPanel >
                          <apex:outputText value="{!grandTotal1}" />&nbsp;/&nbsp;
                          <apex:outputText value="{!grandTotal2}" /> 
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                      </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>
```

Comment: putting under two columns doesn't make sense for my requirements as I need to display (total A / total B) .

Comment: Updated for one column solution

Comment: 1+ for this because this also works. Thanks you all for sharing the solutions.